# In Angular 9, is there a way to inject "strategy" into route component?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

Suppose I have a generic UI component that represent a page. I want to use this component for multiple routes and the behaviour would be different depending on which route loads it.
Therefore I need to inject a "strategy" into this component depending on the route.

Is there a way to do this? Or is this not a good approach?

For reference, the component is a list page where it lists existing records in a table and have basic functionality, such as: edit, view, search etc.
So far I've created multiple very similar components and use them in the route (one for every record types). But this has quite big overhead, e.g. making sure they look the same, making sure they have same functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to give you exact advice without knowing what your "different strategies" involve (and preferable a minimal stackblitz repro), but I guess you could use a [resolver](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve).

Basically you define a resolver which will provide SOMETHING for the specified route. Resolvers have access to current route snapshot and state snapshot, so you can access params, queryParams, etc. to resolve your data. It also works asynchronously.

It might be service (e.g. UserService for users, ProductsService for products, etc. - as long as they share the same interface) that you will use to provide logic in your component.

It might also provide something else - e.g. records, list of columns, etc.

You can also provide different resolvers for different routes, whatever feels best for you.

Then you can access the resolved data in your component using something along those lines:

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.data = this.route.snapshot.data;
}
```

Comment: Careful with using `snapshot` in this scenario where one component is likely reused in different routes. You want to use the subscription instead of the snapshot or the data will not be updated when you visit other routes.